# Exporting coordinates of vertices to CSV

Tags: python, scripting, export, csv

I have a [.3ds file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B92Nk-QHod5xZy1RdnNIWEM4OWc/view?usp=sharing) which I import into Blender. 
[image: vertices]

Now what I'm trying to do is to export the coordinates of vertices into a .ply file. When I export these vertices into a .ply file they are not correct. It seems that it only exports the coordinates of the single face which you can see in the picture. How can I export those vertices correctly?

**EDIT**
The .csv structure:

1;2;3\n

4;5;6\n

...
Each column is separated by a semicolon and each row by a new line.

Comment: Appears the ply exporter does not allow exporting solitary verts (that are not parts of faces). Why not use a different export format?

Comment: I have a script which will convert the ply into .csv. The .csv then goes to Matlab for further manipulation... 
Basically what I need are the data containing the coordinates. I'm okay with any other file type until I will be able to read it and convert it into a .csv

Comment: You can generate your csv directly from blender using the Python API. If you add the CSV structure to your question we can help you write such a script.

Comment: @TLousky I just added the structure of CSV into my question

Comment: Wrote an answer, give it a go and let us know if it works for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate your CSV directly from blender using the script below.
It will generate a semi-colon separated list of coordinates for each vertex in the active mesh.

It requires you to select and set the mesh you want to export as the active object.

```
import bpy

outputFile = 'C:/someFolder/mesh.csv'

verts = [ bpy.context.object.matrix_world * v.co for v in bpy.context.object.data.vertices ]

csvLines = [ ";".join([ str(v) for v in co ]) + "\n" for co in verts ]

f = open( outputFile, 'w' )
f.writelines( csvLines )
f.close()
```

Here's how the CSV data looks like when exporting the coordiantes of a default icosphere (2 subdivisions, 42 verts):

[image]

```
0.0;0.0;-1.0
0.7236073017120361;-0.5257253050804138;-0.44721952080726624
-0.276388019323349;-0.8506492376327515;-0.4472198486328125
-0.8944262266159058;0.0;-0.44721561670303345
-0.276388019323349;0.8506492376327515;-0.4472198486328125
0.7236073017120361;0.5257253050804138;-0.44721952080726624
0.276388019323349;-0.8506492376327515;0.4472198486328125
-0.7236073017120361;-0.5257253050804138;0.44721952080726624
-0.7236073017120361;0.5257253050804138;0.44721952080726624
0.276388019323349;0.8506492376327515;0.4472198486328125
0.8944262266159058;0.0;0.44721561670303345
0.0;0.0;1.0
-0.16245555877685547;-0.49999526143074036;-0.8506544232368469
0.42532268166542053;-0.30901139974594116;-0.8506541848182678
0.26286882162094116;-0.8090116381645203;-0.5257376432418823
0.8506478667259216;0.0;-0.5257359147071838
0.42532268166542053;0.30901139974594116;-0.8506541848182678
-0.525729775428772;0.0;-0.8506516814231873
-0.6881893873214722;-0.49999693036079407;-0.5257362127304077
-0.16245555877685547;0.49999526143074036;-0.8506544232368469
-0.6881893873214722;0.49999693036079407;-0.5257362127304077
0.26286882162094116;0.8090116381645203;-0.5257376432418823
0.9510578513145447;-0.30901262164115906;0.0
0.9510578513145447;0.30901262164115906;0.0
0.0;-0.9999999403953552;0.0
0.5877856016159058;-0.8090167045593262;0.0
-0.9510578513145447;-0.30901262164115906;0.0
-0.5877856016159058;-0.8090167045593262;0.0
-0.5877856016159058;0.8090167045593262;0.0
-0.9510578513145447;0.30901262164115906;0.0
0.5877856016159058;0.8090167045593262;0.0
0.0;0.9999999403953552;0.0
0.6881893873214722;-0.49999693036079407;0.5257362127304077
-0.26286882162094116;-0.8090116381645203;0.5257376432418823
-0.8506478667259216;0.0;0.5257359147071838
-0.26286882162094116;0.8090116381645203;0.5257376432418823
0.6881893873214722;0.49999693036079407;0.5257362127304077
0.16245555877685547;-0.49999526143074036;0.8506543636322021
0.525729775428772;0.0;0.8506516814231873
-0.42532268166542053;-0.30901139974594116;0.8506541848182678
-0.42532268166542053;0.30901139974594116;0.8506541848182678
0.16245555877685547;0.49999526143074036;0.8506543636322021
```

Comment: I get an error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: That means the object is not selected.

Comment: I also have added the .3ds file into my question which I import into blender

Comment: OK, I just ran it once more and I got the coordinates, but all of have have the same value in the 2. colomn which means I get the wrong values

Comment: Hmm. I'll have a go at it with your 3ds file when I get back home later.

Comment: How should I select properly all the contours? Because I believe that I'm doing it the wrong way. Should I hold Shift and the left click on all the shapes under the scenes? I'm new to Blender so I'm not sure. 
When I do it this way all the contours all orange colored except for one which is yellow and I believe that I get the coordinates of the yellow one

Comment: You're right. Select all with the shortcut key A. Then join all to one object with Ctrl + J. Then run the script.

Comment: So that was the problem. Now I 've got it right. Thank you so much!

Comment: somehow the script is not exporting the correct coordinates for me on a bezier curve object when converted to a mesh...not sure why