# Console output to file

Tags: python

My Python script prints coordinates of an empty into the system console. Now I would like to save these coordinates in a file to make them available to another program for further processing.
Is there a possibility for this?

Comment: Hello ! This question is answered there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5214587/7092409

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/exporting-coordinates-of-vertices-to-csv