# What happened with blensor?

Tags: add-on

Is there any replacement for "BlenSor" available?
I mean a different add-on with the same/similar features. It seems there has been no progress since the BlenSor 1.0.18 RC3 release (2018).

BlenSor (https://www.blensor.org/) stands for Blender Sensor Simulation. It simulates the output of ranging technologies such as LIDAR.

Thanks :)

Comment: It would be nice if you explained a bit what the addon does in the question :) FYI it seems this is achievable with Geometry Nodes, as showcased in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tRYX369mvE

Comment: Very interesting videos. The idea would be to do the same and save the coordinates of the points detected by the moving LIDAR. Any suggestion?
I have just edited the initial post with some information about BlenSor. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: Since it creates actual geometry, you can try something like this to write the coordinates to a file : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/exporting-coordinates-of-vertices-to-csv

Comment: I don't see how I can recreate something like in the youtube video with the geometry nodes. I am also very new to Blender. Let's say a few weeks. 
Is there any relevant source or tutorial you think is relevant?

Comment: What happened was that Gschwandtner earned their PhD and eventually left the department and moved on to other things.  I don't think anyone at the university picked up the work when he left, but you'd be better asking them then here.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. I have found this new addon available under the name of Blainder-range-scanner. Does this name ring a bell to anyone? I am trying to install it but for some reason, that I haven't figured it out yet, it's not working.