# Export instances position from Spreadsheet to csv

Tags: geometry-nodes, export, csv, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a method to export the position of my instances to a .csv file to make some considerations in Excel.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers!

EDIT: I don't think this post is the solution
'Saving and loading object name location and rotation of a selection,'
I'm searching how to export the positions of my instances (the origin) from the spreadsheet editor of geometry node, not the mesh vertex

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/exporting-coordinates-of-vertices-to-csv

Comment: I'm sorry, but the vertex coordinates are not the same as the instances origin, nor is the post "Saving and loading object name location and rotation of a selection" because Blender 2.8 did not have a spreadsheet or geometry node!

Comment: In that case please add a little bit more information about your setup. Instances can mean different things in different contexts